# Need help in placing dynamically button in iphone application using objective c language?

Tags: iphone, dynamic-data

> I need your help to create a button dynamically in iphone

Thanks

Comment: please ask your question in a clear manner, other wise it should be downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Cut and paste this into a View-based project's ProjectViewController.m file:

```
- (void) pressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog( @"pressed!" );
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
    [btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake( 20, 20, 200, 100 );
    [self.view addSubview:btn];

}
```

The main thing to remember is that `setBackgroundImage:forState:` will stretch the image to fill the button's frame, while `setImage:forState:` will not.